# Graphics issues durring install on Intel NUC5i7RYH

Tags: intel-graphics

I am installing 14.04.2 on a two brand new Intel NUC's Model NUC5i7RYH.  They have the latest tech for the NUC's but there is something that fails with the graphics.
  When the desktop displays for the installer the window are mostly blank.  Text and icons don't show up so I can't read what to do next. I can get solid light grey background color of a dialog and the desktop is redish.  I can see a continue button but I don't know what will happen if I press it.  Intel reports that this system is compatible with Ubuntu but my two are not behaving.
  Any help would be great. 
   thanks
     clay

Comment: That was it I did not realize that the stable release was so old.  15.04 worked.

Comment: this seems to be a typical problem while installing 14.04.2. i even tried the option for "try ubuntu before installing" and after the desktop shows up various windows don't render correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish an LTS Ubuntu release, then you must install 14.04.X.

The solution is to install **Ubuntu Server 14.04.2** then update your fresh installed system and use `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Graphics will work fine after reboot.